# NAudio Play part of audio from recording file

Tags: c#, audio-recording, naudio

Using NAudio, while recording audio to a file I need to play a part of that file with offsetSampleProvider.SkipOver / offsetSampleProvider.Take

The problem is that I can't open the file with AudioFileReader because it is already in use by WaveFileWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Here is the source code.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;
using static System.Environment;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WaveFileWriter fileWriter;
        WaveOut outputSound;
        WaveIn waveSource;
        RawSourceWaveStream RSS;
        OffsetSampleProvider offsetSampleProvider;
        Stream sourceStream;

        string fileName = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\temp.wav";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            outputSound = new WaveOut();
            waveSource = new WaveIn();
            waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
            waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
            fileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(fileName, waveSource.WaveFormat);
            sourceStream = new MemoryStream();

            waveSource.StartRecording();
        }

        private void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            fileWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            sourceStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RSS = new RawSourceWaveStream(sourceStream, waveSource.WaveFormat);
            RSS.Position = 0;
            offsetSampleProvider = new OffsetSampleProvider(RSS.ToSampleProvider());
            offsetSampleProvider.SkipOver = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
            offsetSampleProvider.Take = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
            outputSound.Init(offsetSampleProvider);
            outputSound.Play();
        }
    }
}
```